# Show 404 after Redux ajax request

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

When users navigate to `/places/:slug` in my React/Redux app, an ajax call is triggered to get the relavant place data from the database.

While this all works as expected I'm not sure how to show a 404 if no place was found. I have a 404 route setup for when users navigate to a non-route but how can I trigger a 404 using Redux?

In my container component I have:

```
this.props.dispatch(fetchPlace(this.props.match.params.slug))
```

and my action:

```
import axios from "axios";

export function fetchPlace(slug) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACE"});
    axios.get("/server/places/" + slug)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACE_FULFILLED", payload: response.data})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACE_REJECTED", payload: err})
      })
  }
}
```

and my reducer:

```
const reducer = (state={
  place: {},
  isFetching: false,
  error: null
}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "FETCH_PLACE" : {
      return { ...state, isFetching: true }
    }
    case "FETCH_PLACE_REJECTED" : {
      return { ...state, isFetching: false, error: action.payload }
    }
    case "FETCH_PLACE_FULFILLED" : {
      return { ...state, isFetching: false, place: action.payload }
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default reducer
```

**Ideas**

I could use another state property in my reducer called `notFound` and initialize it to `false`. Then read the response data payload and detect whether a job has been returned. If not then set `notFound` to `true`. But how do I listen for notFound to be true and trigger a 404?

Comment: What router do you use? Do you have redux integration w/ router?

Comment: I'm using `react-router` v4

Comment: Wrote an answer based on your router lib

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest returning a promise from `fetchPlace` action and catch it in container.

Action code which returns promise

```
export function fetchPlace(slug) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACE"});
      return axios.get("/server/places/" + slug)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACE_FULFILLED", payload: response.data})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACE_REJECTED", payload: err})
     })
  }
}
```

Container code (You must have access to react-router context or history object)

```
this.props.dispatch(fetchPlace(this.props.match.params.slug))
.then(() => {})
.catch(() => {
  //Redirect to 404 page using history object from props
  this.props.history.replace(`404`)

  //Redirect to 404 page using context
  this.context.router.history.replace(`404`)
})
```

Another approach would be checking `notFound` value in `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` method.